# Linq query to Check and get dictionary item from list of dictionary items

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary items,

```
List<Dictionary<string,string>> lstOfDict = new List<Dictionary<string,string>>();
```

Dictionary items:

```
<"name","Adam">
<"mail","abc@abc.com">
<"number",123>
```

These dictionary items are in the list, lstOfDict, I need a linq query to check if list contains a dictionary item having key as "mail", if yes get dictionary item.

I have tried,

```
   var mail = from item in lstOfDict 
               where(x => x.ContainsKey("mail"))
               select item;
```

But with no results, any idea to resolve this is helpful.
Thanks

Comment: use .FirstOrDefault or .ToList to execute the query. like this. `lstOfDict.Where(x => x.ContainsKey("mail")).ToList()`

Comment: Probably `SelectMany()` is what you're looking for.

Comment: What do you mean by "no results"? Is there an error? Is `mail` null? Is it an empty enumeration?

Comment: you'r doing correct, just need to add ToList() extention

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Any method do do this, like that:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> lstOfDict = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();            
lstOfDict.Add(new Dictionary<string, string> 
{ 
    ["name"] = "Adam", 
    ["mail"] = "abc@abc.com"
}); 

var containsEmail = lstOfDict.SelectMany(x => x).Where(x => x.Key == "mail");
```

Comment: Well, OP nneds to pull out the matching key/value pair , I guess.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh Yeah, you rigth, I fixed my code, thanks!!

Comment: I proposed the exact same solution.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh Yeah, the difference between our solution, is that you used ToList, and I don't, I prefer lazy evaluation than eager.

Answer (score 4):

```
try this -

var o = lstOfDict.SelectMany(k => k).Where(key => key.Key == "mail").ToList();
```

Basically the motive here , is , to flatten the `List` of `Dictionary<string ,string>`, then pull out the entry that has a `key == "mail"`.

Comment: what is this .SelectMany(k => k) doing here ?

Comment: @A.T. it does a flatMap

Comment: the expected output for `SelecyMany` operation on `List<List<T>>` is `List<T>`.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
 lstOfDict.Where(x => x.ContainsKey("mail")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code as posted should mean that `mail` is an enumeration of all the dictionaries that have the key "mail". You then need to decide what to do with that, such as:

```
var numberOfMatchingDictionaries = mail.Count();
```

...or:

```
var firstMatchingDictionary = mail.FirstOrDefault();
if (firstMatchingDictionary != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Value is {0}", firstMatchingDictionary["mail"]);
}
```

...or:

```
foreach(var dictionary in mail)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Value is {0}", dictionary["mail"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing it.

First, create some mock data.

```
   List<Dictionary<string, string>> lstOfDict = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
   var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
   dict1.Add("name", "Adam");
   var dict2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
   dict2.Add("mail", "abc@abc.com");
   var dict3 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
   dict3.Add("mail", "xyz@abc.com");
   lstOfDict.Add(dict1);
   lstOfDict.Add(dict2);
   lstOfDict.Add(dict3);
```

The below query will give us an IENumerable collection (collection within a collection) of email addresses.

```
   var emails = lstOfDict.Where(d => d.ContainsKey("mail")).Select(d => d.Values).ToList();
```

You have multiple dictionaries in the list. But each dictionary can have only one item with the key "mail". So calling `First()` should be correct.

```
   foreach (var email in emails)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(email.First());// here we are printing the email addresses.
    }
```